# I can't add an element to the list. It returns null. How can I add it?

Tags: java, arrays, spring, algorithm

My controller class:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/uniqueUrl")
        @ResponseBody
        public ResponseEntity<MyResponse> urlGenerator(@RequestBody MyRequest myRequest){
            log.info("Request for url : ", myRequest); 
            MyResponse myResponse= this.generateUrlService.urlGenerator(myRequest);
            log.info("generateUniqueUrl response: ", myResponse.getLongUniqueUrlList());
            return ResponseEntity.accepted().body(myResponse);
        }
```

MyRequest class:

```
@Data
public class MyRequestimplements Serializable {

    @NotNull(message = "Url cannot be null or empty")
    private String url;
    @NotNull(message = "count cannot be null or empty")
    private int cound;
}
```

My service implemantation :

```
@Override
    public myResponse urlGenerator(MyRequest myRequest) {

        log.info("urlGenerator started..");

        myUrlRequestValidator.validate(myRequest);

        String longUrl = myRequest.getUrl();
        int count = myRequest.getCount();

        List<String> uniqueUrlList = Arrays.asList(new String[count]);

        for (String string : uniqueUrlList) {
            string = longUrl + "/?";

            for (int i = 0; i < rand.nextInt(11)+4; i++) {
                string += letters.get(rand.nextInt(35));
            }
            uniqueUrlList.add(string);
            log.info(string);
        }

        MyResponse response = new MyResponse();
        response.setLongUniqueUrlList(uniqueUrlList);
        return response;
    }
```

MyResponse class:

@Data
public class MyResponse extends BaseResponse {

```
private List<String> longUniqueUrlList;
private List<String> shortUrlList;
```

}

In the method where my Controller and Service class is as follows, the result of uniqueUrlList returns null. I want to add each string formed by the add method to the list, but it does not add it. Can you help me where am I going wrong?

edit1 : When I change the random url generation and adding to the list in this way, it does not enter the for loop, or when I do not change the loop and only define it as an arraylist, it gives a Null error in the add method. How can I solve this? It's such an easy thing, but I don't understand why I can't do it?

```
List<String> uniqueUrlList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        String string = null;
        for ( int j = 0;  j  < count;  j++) {
            string = longUrl + "/?";

            for (int i = 0; i < rand.nextInt(11)+4; i++) {
                string += letters.get(rand.nextInt(35));
            }
            uniqueUrlList.add(string);
            log.info(string);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is null because your `List<String> uniqueUrlList` is initialized with `Arrays.asList` which are fixed in size and unmodifiable, as specified in the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-). The `Arrays.asList(new String[count])` is also empty as there are no elements inside the `new String[count]`.

Instead you should initialize it with a `new ArrayList<String>()`:

```
List<String> uniqueUrlList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Where you can then modify the list as you please, using a loop to add to your `uniqueUrlList` as many as `myRequest.getCount()` times.

Comment: Thank you very much for your descriptive comment. I changed it as you showed, but this time it gives a null error when I use the .add method, or when I change the for loop, it does not enter the for loop. Any chance you could show me the for loop and how I should add it?

Comment: The list returned by `Arrays.asList` is not unmodifiable. You can **replace** items in the list (using `set`), but you can't **add** or **remove** items as it has a fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize a list by

```
List<String> uniqueUrlList = new ArrayList<>();
```